# 1 tomato plant out of 4 is stunted, light green, has brown dots on leaves + stem (no yellow)

Tags: tomatoes, wilt

Before I send this plant to the great farm in the sky, would anyone have any armchair suggestions on remedies I can try please? I think the soil / environment is OK based on the plant next to it being healthy.

These are a strain my great grandfather cultivated in northern England, so I'm trying to keep them going. I planted seeds I kept from last years crop. They create a vast amount of golf ball sized tomatoes, no shelter in central London.

This plant sprouted much after the others and generally looked a bit weak, like it didn't have good roots. I planted it deep and it appeared to recover and looked healthy for a few weeks. After the recent sun, the other 3 have shot ahead. I can't find evidence of bugs nomming it. All 4 plants have brown spots/streaks on their incredibly thick stems.

Many thank yous in advance!

[image: Compared to its cousins]

Leaves have bumps, brownness, curling slightly.
[image: Extremities]

Brown streaks on stem / leaves. 
[image: Blobs]

New leaves are pretty OK looking.
[image: New leaves]